# Can't print bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

It just does not work, no matter how I try. Currently I use

`\bibliography{lit.bib}`

before starting the document, then

`\printbibliography{lit.bib}`

before ending it. I can refer to entries in the bibliography just fine in text, the references will be made and named as they are in the bibliography, however the page on which I put the `\printbib...` command simply says "`lit.bib`"

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex

Edit:

```
\documentclass[english,parskip=half]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,},exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins} 


%\def\fps@figure{htbp}
%\def\fps@table{htbp}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black]{hyperref} 
\bibliography{lit.bib} 
\addbibresource{lit.bib}



\addto\extrasenglish{%  
 \def\subsectionautorefname{Abschnitt} von Unterabschnitt auf Abschnitt
 \def\figureautorefname{Abb.} 
} 


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

(Stuff from titlepage here)

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\input{chapter/Abstract}
\newpage
....(more chapters here
\printbibliography{lit.bib}
\end{document}
```

Edit Nr 2: Current code:

```
\documentclass[english,parskip=half]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,},exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins} 

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

%\def\fps@figure{htbp}
%\def\fps@table{htbp}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black]{hyperref} 
\addbibresource{lit.bib}



\addto\extrasenglish{%  
 \def\subsectionautorefname{Abschnitt}
 \def\figureautorefname{Abb.}
} 


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

(content of title page here)

\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
(chapters here)
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Version nr 2 gives the error "option clash for package biblatex"

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! A minimal (non)working example would help to help. Dib you run `bibtex` or `biber`? The normal cycle is `pdflatex -> bibtex/biber -> pdflatex -> pdflatex`.  It seems that you use `biblatex`. In such a case, you should add to your preamble: `\addbibresource{lit.bib}` rather than `\bibliography`, and simply write `printbibliography` (no argument \ tat's why you find ‘lit.bib’  in your .pdf)).

Comment: I just tried out the cycle you described and nothing changed, although I also did not get any error messages so it appears to compile "correctly"

Comment: What does the `.blg` file say?

Comment: There is no .blg file ?!

Comment: Looks like you are failing to run Biber, which is the standard 'back-end' for `biblatex`. See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations for some guidance.

Comment: 1. These tell me to access the .blg file which I don't have and 2. mention non-working citations, however my citations work.

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing commands form `bibtex` and `biblatex`. If you use `biblatex` (i.e., `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`, then the first command should be `\addbibresource{lit.bib}` and at the place where you want your bibliography to be printed, use `\printbibliography`. Nowadays, the default engine is `biber` (instead of `bibtex`, so you want to use `bibtex` you have to add `backend=bibtex` option to biblatex, `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`).

If you do not use `biblatex`, then you should use `\bibliographystyle{...}` and `\bibliography{lit}`.

Comment: Trying to use \usepackage[...]{biblatex} gives me the error "Option clash for package biblatex"

Comment: I  used  `...` to indicate there are some options (which I don't know since there is no minimal working example.  Remove `\bibliography{lit.bib}` and add `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`, and remove `{lit.bib}` from `\printbibliography`

Comment: Still doesn't work. It just creates an empty page with the words "lit.bib"

Comment: you have to add `\usepacakge[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` before `\addbibresource{lit.bib}`, and remove `\bibliograpahy{lit.bib}` and `{lit.bib}` after `\printbibliography`, and include a `\cite` command.

Comment: you have two  lines with `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`. combine them in a single one, I.e., `\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`

Answer (score 0):

Your (modified) code, slightly more minimal than what you posted, runs fine on my system. I also corrected the syntax and I obtain a `.blg` file, so try this:

```
\documentclass[english,parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}

\addto\extrasenglish{%
 \def\subsectionautorefname{Abschnitt} von Unterabschnitt auf Abschnitt
 \def\figureautorefname{Abb.}
}
....(more chapters here)

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Disregard, made a mistake. Still compiles fine, still no biblopgraphy :/

Comment: You're supposed to have a `lit.bib` file. If you have no .bib file, you can't hope to print a bibliography.

Comment: Of course I do, and there's an entry I can cite even.

Comment: OJ Can you post a minimal working example that shows the problem.

Comment: Put a second edit into my original topic

Comment: to successfully compile the MWE in this answer you have to compile your bibliography with `biber`, not `bibtex`

Comment: I works fine, after I've grouped the two calls to biblatex into one,(that's the reason of the`option clash`). It works also with `bibtex`, but as said @Guido, you should use `biber`; it has many more possibilities and it understands `utf8`.

Comment: If I open my .tex file with biber all it does is create a weird performance-monitor file...

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You open your .tex file with an editor.

Comment: Then... how do I use biber? I'm confused now.

Comment: Which editor do you use? Which OS?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit, editor TexMaker

Comment: Then probably you don't have biber installed, for it comes only with the 32-bit version. However, you can install the 32-bit version by yourself and make it work. It's fairly easy.